# Poetry can't find Python 2.7 via Pyenv

Tags: python, version, python-poetry

With Poetry version: 1.1.13 I get the following error when trying to use Python 2.7.18 via Pyenv...

```
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
```

This occurs when 2.7.18 is set up locally (`pyenv local 2.7.18`) and globally (`pyenv global 2.7.18`). Running `python` within the directory in question launches the terminal...

```
Python 2.7.18 (v2.7.18:8d21aa21f2, Apr 20 2020, 13:25:05) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

But when I install Python 3.9.6 and set it as the local Python version, Poetry works perfectly correctly!

Has anyone seen this before? Am I missing something?

Comment: Not related but Python 2.7 is pretty old so you shouldn't use it.

Comment: @BrainFl absolutely. This is some legacy application that I aim to port.

Comment: My understanding is that Poetry still supports 2.7 but loses it in version 1.2

Comment: Ye I know that, I just wanna say you shouldn't use Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*%USERPROFILE%.poetry\bin\poetry.bat* was calling `Python3` which can't find Python2 installs. When installing Poetry [get-poetry.py](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/blob/master/get-poetry.py) is called. The `_which_python` method (line 666) determines if the call in poetry.bat is `Python3` or `Python` by which version of Python it finds during the install.

If you have already installed Poetry simply modify the poetry.bat file to be `python`. For future installations with Pyenv ensure that a 2.7 Python version is set as global.